# Error: UIAlertController when transitioning to other view

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

When I add a function transition to other view which name "Result", to a object of UIAlertController, it transition to a black view and I can't do anything in it. Help me fix it.

```
var controller : UIAlertController?

@IBAction func next() {
   controller = UIAlertController(title: "Warning:", message: "Are you sure ?", preferredStyle: .Alert)

   let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Sure!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:{(paramAction: UIAlertAction!) in self.transition()})
   controller?.addAction(action)
   self.presentViewController(controller!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func transition() {
    let secondViewController:Result = Result()
    self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: You cannot initialize a view controller with the default initializer `()`. Either the controller must be designed in Interface Builder or be loaded from a xib file.

Comment: I already designed in Interface Builder, its name is Result. But I need to add transition function by code because I need add it to alert action. Either you may teach me about how to transition to other view by alert action. Thanks.